# PHP datetime hourly interval

Tags: php

I need a script to generate thousand rows of date time with hourly interval . (e.g 24/10/14 12:00:00 , 24/10/14 13:00:00 so forth and so on) Thanks in advance.

```
$updatedDateTimeList = array();
$dateTimeList=array("2014-10-01 00:00:00","2014-11-01 00:00:00");
foreach ($dateTimeList as $dateTime)
{
    $time = substr($dateTime, 11);
    if (substr($time, 0, 2) < 24)
    {
        $updatedDateTimeList[] = substr($dateTime, 0, 11) + (substr($time, 0, 2) +              1) + substr($dateTime, 13);
    } else {
        $updatedDateTimeList[] = substr($dateTime, 0, 8) + (substr($dateTime, 8, 2) + 1                                                     ) + " 00" + substr($dateTime, 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [DateTime::modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the startdate and enddate limits ana starting from start date in a while loop you can add 1 hour on every pass. Check the following code.

```
$updatedDateTimeList = array();
$startdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime ("2014-10-01 00:00:00"));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime ("2014-11-01 00:00:00"));
$updatedDateTimeList[] = $startdate; //store the first value
while ($startdate < $enddate)
{
  $startdate = strtotime($startdate)+3600; //add one hour to $startdate
  $startdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $startdate); 
  $updatedDateTimeList[] = $startdate; // store to the array
}

 print_r($updatedDateTimeList);
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude. When i populate the database , my other field (temperature) is not randomized anymore. Any idea why?                  for ($x=0; $x<=5; $x++) {
 $min=25;
 $max =34;
 $temp = rand($min,$max);
 
 $myArray = array("cck", "amk");
 shuffle($myArray);
 $location = $myArray[0];

Comment: The piece of code for the $temp value seems fine. Maybe  ask a new question providing some more code beacause comments serve another purpose. For the initial question if my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted.